# Comparing creation/modification date of NSData objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdata

At first I have a plist file in app bundle. At some point the file can get updated (downloaded into Documents Folder). Whats the best way to know which file is newer? The mainbundle plist could get updated with new App Version and then the downloaded one would be the oldest.
I do have a timestamp inside the plist but I actually don't want to load each of them into memory to be able to compare the dates, as each takes 1-2 seconds.
Is there some kind of creation date that I could compare?

Comment: 1-2 seconds to load a plist?

Comment: using NSPropertyListSerialization (NSData to NSDictionary) on iP4

Comment: I honestly don't see a need for anything like that on the file. You could always just add a number onto the end of the filename. Make a var n or something and for every file, do <fileName>n++. (EX: file1, file2, file3) whichever is the highest, is the newest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary* dict = [NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
NSDate* date = [dict fileModificationDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`-[NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath%3aerror%3a) to get the filesystem-level attributes of each plist, then compare values for modification dates (using the `NSFileModificationDate` string constant).